# Swift conditional conformance with two cases

Tags: json, swift, generics, protocols, decodable

The short question is how can I make a type conditionally conform to a protocol with two conditions when either one of them is met?

I have a generic type `NetworkResponse<Data>`. It represents server response. Here is how it is defined:

```
enum NetworkResponse<Data> {
    case success(Data)
    case error(ServerError)
}
```

I want to make `NetworkResponse` to conform `Decodable`. Here is my server response format:

```
{
    "data": {
        "someKey": "someValue",
        "anotherKey": 15
    },
    "meta": {
        "returnCode": 0,
        "returnMessage": "operation is successful"
    }
}
```

The `data` part depends on what request is made. The `meta` part represents some meta data about response. Like whether it is success or if not what is the error.

So here is how I implemented `Decodable`:

```
extension NetworkResponse: Decodable where Data: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case meta
        case data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let metaValue = try container.decode(ServerError.self, forKey: .meta)

        if metaValue.code != 0 {
            self = .error(metaValue)
        } else {
            self = .success(try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .data))
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. But here is my problem. For some apis which don't need to return any data the `data` part in response is omitted. In this case my response would look like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "returnCode": 0,
        "returnMessage": "operation is successful"
    }
}
```

In this case I want to decode the response json as `NetworkResponse<Void>`. But since `Void` can not conform to `Decodable` (since it is non nominal type) compiler gives error.

To overcome this I tried to create more specialized extension of `Decodable` where `Data` is `Void` like this:

```
extension NetworkResponse: Decodable where Data == Void {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let metaValue = try container.decode(AppErrors.Server.self, forKey: CodingKeys.meta)

        if metaValue.code != 0 {
            self = .error(metaValue)
        } else {
            self = .success(())
        }
    }
}
```

But still compiler complines like: `Conflicting conformance of 'NetworkResponse<Data>' to protocol 'Decodable'; there cannot be more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds`.

So how can I create seperate `init(from:)` function that is used for when `Data` is `Void`?

Comment: I believe `Data` should be optional? Other option can be addition of another enum case something successful.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly urge you to change the generic parameter's type name away from `Data` since it's too easily confused with `Foundation.Data` which is widely used throughout Swift.

On to the problem itself, you can make an empty struct to represent "void" and add a new case to your `NetworkResponse`:

```
struct EmptyData: Decodable {}

enum NetworkResponse<T> {
    case success(T)
    case successWithEmptyData
    case error(ServerError)
}

extension NetworkResponse: Decodable where T: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case meta
        case data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let metaValue = try container.decode(ServerError.self, forKey: .meta)

        if metaValue.code != 0 {
            self = .error(metaValue)
        } else if T.self == EmptyData.self {
            self = .successWithEmptyData
        } else {
            self = .success(try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .data))
        }
    }
}

let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(NetworkResponse<EmptyData>.self, from: jsonData)
```

Alternatively, you can make your `.success` case contains a `T?` when you expect no data in return and decode accordingly.